# The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to integrate Cloud Firestore to and Android app but all I get is this error every single time:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Note: /home/tr/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.4+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 76095 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 10s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Please provide more details, what are you trying to perform? Are you following a tutorial or doc? Did it work before? Were changes done to your code before these Error messages appeared?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just have to change the **minsdkversion to 24 instead of 16**.

In `android\app\build.gradle`

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.example"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }
```

It worked or me. ;)

Answer (score 86):

In the `build.gradle` for the app:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Change the `minSdkversion` from 16 to 21, this worked in my case.

Answer (score 20):

I have experienced similar problem while coding with flutter but `BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        11.0s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
    To disable the shrinker, pass the`--no-shrink`flag to this command.
    To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

But i have managed to run my app and this is how i did it.

1.I located android/app/build.gradle file
2. Then access below code in the gradle file

```
    buildTypes {
    release {

        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

and changed it to

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true

        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

}

The app was able to run in Android emulator

Answer (score 9):

There are two different answers to this issue but I think the most appropriate is the one given by @Sarang Pal
This is the official explanation by Google:

Troubleshooting Android build fail:

If you're planning to develop using an Android device or emulator, you'll need to handle multidex support -- otherwise, your build will fail with "Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file."

By default, Flutter supports Android SDK v16 (Jelly Bean, released 2012), but multidex doesn't really work with Jelly Bean (though, it's possible). Configuring Jelly Bean to work is beyond the scope of this codelab, so we'll change the minimum target SDK version from v16 to v21 (Lollipop, released 2014).

To change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says minSdkVersion 16.
2. Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
3. Save the file.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html#3

Answer (score 6):

navigate to {your-app-name}\android\app\build.gradle

// change your minSdkVersion from 16 to 21

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.testapp"
    minSdkVersion 21 
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply change `minSdkVersion` to 21 then it will be working

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried every step from above but without success.

Finally, I solved with these commands inside the terminal:

```
$: flutter clean

$: flutter pub get
```

Everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I managed to solve this issue in the easiest way!

**Important:** Just go to  **app:level module** `android/app/build.gradle` and place `multiDexEnabled true`

```
android {
.
.
.
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.you_app_name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

Android applications by default have SingleDex support which limits your application to have only 65536 methods(references). So multidexEnabled = true simply means that now you can write more than 65536 methods(references) in your application.

Try this, it may work and finally resolve this issue   `[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode. To disable the shrinker, pass the --no-shrink flag to this command.`

Hope!!! it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have added these lines to app level gradle file in Android to disable minify i.e. shrinking of code

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Go to android/app/build.gradle** and then copy and paste this and change the application id.

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "your application id"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had ran

```
flutter create .
```

in order to generate windows, and web folders
but since my project was setup to use java as the native instead of Kotlin the the generator created a Kotlin Folder in /android/src/main which caused confusion i think i just deleted it and it worked for me.

Comment: i had same problem, Worked for me. just deleted kotlin folder.

Answer (score 1):

At android\app\build.gradle file:
Just change minSdkVersion 16 to 21

> minSdkVersion 21

And it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To change the minimum target SDK version:

1. Open android/app/build.gradle, then find the line that says minSdkVersion 16.
2. Change that line to minSdkVersion 21.
3. Save the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i fixed mine:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I faced this problem because i created a MainActivity.java file manually as my flutter project did not create it.

I tried all the things in documentation like

```
         minifyEnabled true
         shrinkResources true
         minSdkVersion 21
```

but they didn't work.

I analyzed the code and **deleted MainAcivity.kt** Kotlin file. Now it works.

Comment: Thank you bro, i had the same situation. After deleting the MainActivity.kt it's works for me.

Comment: Yeah this worked for me too. The problem is that there where TWO MainActivity files due to android studio stupidly creating both and trying to mindmeld them

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.placementapp"
        minSdkVersion 23 //replace 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also faced this error, while I was working with 'cloud firestore' for the first time, You should change your "Android Level build.gradle"

Android Level 'build.gradle'

Make Sure :

```
defaultConfig {
   "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I just changed my minSdkVersion from 24 to 26: ***minSdkVersion 26***