# How to solve shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode

Tags: android, flutter, plugins

So, I recently added the plugin [desktop_drop](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_drop) to my application. This app runs both on Mobile  devices, android and iOS and is also optimised for desktop as well. MacOs and Windows.

I recently implemented the feature, dragging files from the computer into the app to upload it. On desktop platform, this works beautifully. However, when I run the code on my android device to test it (make sure all is well). It fails. Starts to tell me the following:

***Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.            │
│ To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.      │
│ To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code***

Now, I have checked other similar question on stackoverflow like the following: [Flutter :The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745249/flutter-the-shrinker-may-have-failed-to-optimize-the-java-bytecode)

First solution says, have minSdkVersion to atleast 21. Mine is on 23.
Next solution says: disable shrink wrap, by setting minifyEnabled to false. I did this, and the app refused to compile. Debug console said, minifyEnabled cannot be false.
Another solution said, set multiDexEnabled to true. Did this. But the shrinker warning remained. I am out of ideas.

Is the desktop_drop plugin clashing with the android app. On the home page of the plugin it says it is compatible with android. So, I am out of ideas.

Anyone has a solution for me to get this app running. To get this shrinker error to stop showing. So, the app can compile in peace, would be much appreciated.